# Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'

Tags: python, django, post, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to s3. I continue getting this error:

```
Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'.  If it is specified, please check the order of the fields.
```

here is my code I am sending to s3:

```
 content_type = "image/JPEG"
    key = 'uploads/filename.jpg'
    acl = 'public-read'
    bucket = None

    params_raw = create_upload_data(content_type,key,acl,bucket)

    params = { 'policy': params_raw['policy'],'acl':acl,'signature':params_raw['signature'],'key':params_raw['key'],'Content-Type':params_raw['Content-Type'],'AWSAccessKeyId':params_raw['AWSAccessKeyId'],'success_action_status':params_raw['success_action_status'],'file': binary_data}
    r = requests.post(params_raw['form_action'],data=params,files={'file':binary_data})
    return JsonResponse({'request':str(r.text)},safe=False)
```

I've tried moving the param 'key' to the front of params but that still produces the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python dicts do not have an order. When serializing them, there is no way to predict the order of the key/values pairs. You may try again with an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Done! I did not post it as an answer at first because I was not sure it was your problem.

Comment: no problem thanks for the help! I didn't know dictionaries didn't retain there order in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dicts are unordered. When serializing them, there is no way to predict the order of the key/values pairs.

Try again with an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Edit:
As of Python 3.6, dicts are ordered by default, this is an implementation detail, not a new standard. Keep using `OrderedDict`, it is more explicit, more compatible and future proof.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error.  What order are you suppose to put the values in?

Comment: I do not know, my answer was only Python related, I have no knowledge of Bucket